# How to document a function that returns an ES6 class expression with JSDoc?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, webstorm, jsdoc3, es6-class

I am trying desperately to document a function that returns an ES6 class with JSDoc, and as I use Webstorm, I'd love if it worked with its inspector.

Here is a dummy example:

```
/**
 * @param {*} foo
 * @return {?????}
 */
const classFactory = (foo) => class {
    constructor() {
        this.bar = foo
    }
}

const MyClass = classFactory('foo')
```

And I have no idea what return type to give in the JSDoc here...

Comment: Thinking literally, the answer is `{Function}`, but it's not really a very satisfying answer...

Comment: Have the exact same question, how to document both a class/constructor as a returning type and also as a function argument.